# Strange Offsetting in IE (all versions) compared to other browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a pretty simple css layout for a plate of information, you can find it at : http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/pRq8Z/2/

It works fine in all browsers, but in IE, it has this awkward 'offset' of 65 to the `.links` section, and so it shows in the wrong place. Here on the jsfiddle, the flaw is visible, but it's not that obvious - but in the entire webpage, it makes a pretty huge difference. The `.links` pane is padded wrong in IE.

Is there anything I can do about this retarded 'offset' that seems to come from nowhere in IE? (All versions, Even 9.0)

### CSS RESET

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, code,
del, dfn, em, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode'; 
    font-size: 11px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    margin: 0px auto; 
    width: 960px; 
    position: relative; 
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section { 
    display:block;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}

a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

/* change colors to suit your needs */
ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000; 
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    cursor:help;
}

/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;   
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}

/* Remove the bullets on ordered and unordered lists. */
ol,ul { list-style:none; }

/* Tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup. */
table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0; }
caption, th, td { text-align: left; font-weight: normal; }
table, td, th { vertical-align: middle; }

/* Remove border on linked images. */
a img { border: none; }
a { outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
a:active, a:visited, a:link { text-decoration: none; }

:focus { outline: 0; }

/* Make sure that all input elements have default margins and padding. */
input { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }
```

Comment: @Ciel I'm not sure that I see the issue. Offset in which direction? I'm testing in IE9.

Comment: It seems almost arbitrary. In my actual application, it adds offset to the top, but in jsfiddle, it adds offset to the bottom.

Comment: @Ciel Do you have a CSS reset stylesheet? If not, I believe that would solve your issue with IE.

Comment: Yes, I have a reset stylesheet. I'll post it.

Comment: Alright, I have posted my css reset sheet.

Comment: @Ciel I am unable to recognize any difference between IE9 and Chrome. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Hrnm. Changing it to a `ul` instead of a `div` seems to have corrected the issue. That still doesn't make much sense. But can you post your answer as an official one so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I'm not sure but maybe using UL's instead of DIV's would somehow correct the issue... `:)`

Comment: I did some further tweaking and changing the `ul` to have `absolute` positioning instead of `relative` made it easier, too. IE just has a quirky box model, in all versions, it seems.

Comment: @Ciel Do you use a correct DOCTYPE? (For instance: `<!DOCTYPE html>`). If yes, then IE should display the page in standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

You have something that is triggering compatibility mode. Maybe you have that site, and fiddler in the compatibility mode setting.

to do a test, copy all that into a file, and test with and without the doctype as html. you will see that without  you get the weird offset. with it, the offset is gone.

using ul instead of div only solves it because in compatibility mode, text nodes out of li have no size. in div they have.